# Limit digits of whole/integral part of a decimal number using regex

Tags: regex

I have a regex `(^[1-9]\d*\.?\d{0,2})` to filter a decimal number input.

This is how I think it works:

```
part1: [1-9]     - start with a non-zero number
part2: \d*       - match 0 or more digits
part3: \.?       - maybe match a dot
part4: \d{0,2}   - match 0 to 2 digits
```

For a input of `1234567890.56566456465aa`, I get a valid match of `1234567890.56`

I want to restrict number of digits for `\d*` from `part2`. So, I tried to replace it with `\d{0,3}`. For same input, I get a match of `123456`. This is how I think it gave me this result:

```
1   - from [1-9]
234 - from \d{0,3}
56  - from \d{0,2}
```

The number part before . (dot) should be 0 to 3 character long. Or, match should skip using `part4` if `part3` doesn't exist. For e.g.

```
1234567890.56566456465aa -> 1234 
1234.567890              -> 1234.56
```

How can I do this? Here's related [regexr](https://regexr.com/6ddqn) link.

Comment: For `8.a`. Do you really want to match the dot too? And for `00001.1`, don't you want to match `1.1`?

Comment: I think this is what you want - [`^[1-9]\d{0,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?`](https://regex101.com/r/5DLKUq/2)

Comment: @rupinderjeet after the decimal, you should have atleast 1 or atmost 2 gigits so, you should be using `{1,2}` and not `{0,2}`

Comment: @JvdV For Price Input. User can only set a price of 4 digits or less. And, I want to allow fractional part of two digits. This regex is passed to an input filter. So, after typing `1234`, if user types another digit, input-filter rejects that. If user adds a dot after `1234`, input-filter allows fractional part of two digits. For `8.a`, `8.` is needed to allow a dot through input-filter, and for `00001.1`, only input starting with non-zero number is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5DLKUq/2)**

---

**Explanation:**

- `^` - matches the start of the string
- `[1-9]` - matches a single digit in the range `1` to `9`
- `\d{0,3}` - matches at-least 0 or at-most 3 occurrences of any digit
- `(?:\.\d{0,2})?` - matches the optional decimal and fractional part of the number. The fractional part matched will have atleast 1 digit or at most 2 digits

Edit:
To extract `8.` for inputs `8.a`, you can change the regex to - [`^[1-9]\d{0,3}(?:\.\d{0,2})?`](https://regex101.com/r/5DLKUq/1)

Comment: I needed to allow matches of `8.` for input of `8.a`. See my comment above for explanation.

Comment: @rupinderjeet have updated the solution for that use-case